What was this african american family funeral comedy movie?
I saw in Jay Leno show I guess back in 2011 or 2010. An African american actor is Jay Lenos guest and they were talking about a comedy movie. Then they are showed some scenes, a family member died. I guess there was 5 or so African american actors in the main roles and there was funny things happens in funeral I guess main subject of the movie is funeral. And scene showed in Jay Leno, a 2-3 main guys are preparing or something for funeral in a room.

Death at a Funeral (2010)
It is about a funeral, there are several black actors (Keith David, Danny Glover, Kevin Hart, Martin Lawrence, Chris Rock, Tracy Morgan, Columbus Short, etc.) in it, and it was made in 2010. 
More info on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_at_a_Funeral_(2010_film)
Trailer:



If you Google it, there should be a video of Tracy Morgan in the Jay Leno show talking about the movie here, although I cannot play the video (I can hear only some rap music):
http://www.rapbasement.com/videos/tracy-morgan-on-jay-leno-show-talking-death-at-a-funeral-movie.html
You can watch the complete movie here:




i guess it is. im looking for it now.

yes this is. looks like similar house. i wasnt see this scenes in jay leno, and in jay leno they arent showed all actors just 1 actor this is reason why i cant be sure in the first time, so i checked some scenes.
